# How can I mock the Response.StatusCode with Moq?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, moq

I have the following method:

```
    public void SetHttpStatusCode(HttpStatusCode httpStatusCode)
    {
        Response.StatusCode = (int)httpStatusCode;
    }
```

And the following test:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SetHttpStatusCode_SetsCorrectStatusCode()
    {
        //Arrange
        //Any url will suffice
        var mockHttpContext = TestHelpers.MakeHttpContext(""); 
        mockHttpContext.SetupSet(x => x.Response.StatusCode = It.IsAny<int>());

        //creates an instance of an asp.net mvc controller
        var controller = new AppController()
        {
         ControllerContext = new ControllerContext() { 
                   HttpContext = mockHttpContext.Object }
                             };

        // Act
        controller.SetHttpStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        //Assert
        mockHttpContext.VerifySet(x => x.Response.StatusCode = It.IsAny<int>());
    }
```

Also, Here is MakeHttpContext

```
 public static Mock<HttpContextBase> MakeHttpContext(string url)
    {
        var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        var mockRequest = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        var mockResponse = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
        var mockSession = new Mock<HttpSessionStateBase>();

        //request
        mockRequest.Setup(x => x.AppRelativeCurrentExecutionFilePath).Returns(url);
        mockHttpContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(mockRequest.Object);

        //response
        mockResponse.Setup(x => x.ApplyAppPathModifier(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns<string>(x => x);
        mockHttpContext.Setup(x => x.Response).Returns(mockResponse.Object);

        //session
        mockHttpContext.Setup(x => x.Session).Returns(mockSession.Object);

        return mockHttpContext;
    }
```

When I run the test, I get the following exception:

```
    Test method PA.Tests.Controllers.AppControllerTest.SetHttpStatusCode_SetsCorrectStatusCode
threw exception: 


      Moq.MockException: 
        Expected invocation on the mock at least once, 
        but was never performed: x => x.StatusCode = It.IsAny<Int32>()

        Configured setups:
        x => x.StatusCode = It.IsAny<Int32>(), Times.Never
        No invocations performed.
```

How does Moq expect/require invocations to be called? I've debugged the SetHTTPStatusCode method, the response object is indeed a mocked object, however Moq insists that there was no invocation. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you could use HttpStatusCodeResult?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You haven't shown what your `TestHelpers.MakeHttpContext` method does so it's a bit difficult to understand what's going on.

Try like this:

```
// Arrange
var mockHttpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
var response = new Mock<HttpResponseBase>();
mockHttpContext.SetupGet(x => x.Response).Returns(response.Object);

//creates an instance of an asp.net mvc controller
var controller = new AppController()
{
    ControllerContext = new ControllerContext() 
    { 
        HttpContext = mockHttpContext.Object 
    }
};

// Act
controller.SetHttpStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.OK);

//Assert
response.VerifySet(x => x.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK);
```

Comment: Darin, Thanks for the reply. I've added the MakeHttpContext method to the code sample. It seems like I am hitting the major points, namely the SetupGet for Response. However, I still get the same problem.

Comment: Yes. I also tried your sample. I replaced my entire test with your sample - still the same exception from Moq. I am using Moq 4.0 if that makes a difference

Comment: This is doubly weird. I did a Clean Build on the entire solution, reran your code sample, and it works fine now. Thanks, Darin!

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I am trying to do the same but getting error on following line ControllerContext = new ControllerContext() 
    { 
        HttpContext = mockHttpContext.Object 

It says cannot implicitly convert type "System.Web.Mvc.ControllerContext" to "System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControlerContext"
    }